# How to pass body to express router for PUT request?

Tags: node.js, express, routerjs

I'm trying to create a PUT request using express.js, but I keep getting this error stating that the `body is not defined`. But when I print the `req` to the console, I do see `body` with the data.

**Express**

```
router.put('/category-statement/:corporate_statement_link_id', function(req, res){

    console.log("req: ",req);
    var reqBody = req.body;
    var id = req.params.corporate_statement_link_id;

    console.log("Body: ", body);
    console.log("id:", id);


    let sql = `UPDATE corporate_statements
               SET corporate_statement = ? WHERE corporate_statement_link_id = ?`;

    db.run(sql,[reqBody.corporate_statement, id], (err, row) =>{
        if(err){
            res.status(500).send(err);
        }
        res.send(row)
    });

 })
```

**Angular Service**

```
updateCorporateStatementStatus(corporate_statement_link_id:number, corporate_statement:ICorporateStatementInfo){
    console.log("corporate statement", corporate_statement);
    const headers= new HttpHeaders()
      .set('content-type', 'application/json')
      .set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');

      var body = corporate_statement; // copying to body thinking router.put is specifically looking for body
      console.log(corporate_statement);
      
    return this.http.put<ICorporateStatementInfo>('/api/v1/statements/category-statement/' + corporate_statement_link_id, body, {headers})
      .subscribe(data => {
        console.log(data);
      })
  }
```

**req print**

This is just a part of the `req` from `router.put`

```
  params: { corporate_statement_link_id: '3' },
  query: {},
  res: ServerResponse {
    _events: [Object: null prototype] {
      finish: [Array],
      end: [Function: onevent]
    },
    _eventsCount: 2,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    outputData: [],
    outputSize: 0,
    writable: true,
    _last: false,
    chunkedEncoding: false,
    shouldKeepAlive: true,
    useChunkedEncodingByDefault: true,
    sendDate: true,
    _removedConnection: false,
    _removedContLen: false,
    _removedTE: false,
    _contentLength: null,
    _hasBody: true,
    _trailer: '',
    finished: false,
    _headerSent: false,
    socket: TLSSocket {
      _tlsOptions: [Object],
      _secureEstablished: true,
      _securePending: false,
      _newSessionPending: false,
      _controlReleased: true,
      secureConnecting: false,
      _SNICallback: null,
      servername: 'localhost',
      alpnProtocol: 'http/1.1',
      authorized: false,
      authorizationError: null,
      encrypted: true,
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 11,
      connecting: false,
      _hadError: false,
      _parent: [Socket],
      _host: null,
      _readableState: [ReadableState],
      readable: true,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _writableState: [WritableState],
      writable: true,
      allowHalfOpen: false,
      _sockname: null,
      _pendingData: null,
      _pendingEncoding: '',
      server: [Server],
      _server: null,
      ssl: [TLSWrap],
      _requestCert: false,
      _rejectUnauthorized: true,
      timeout: 120000,
      parser: [HTTPParser],
      on: [Function: socketListenerWrap],
      addListener: [Function: socketListenerWrap],
      prependListener: [Function: socketListenerWrap],
      _paused: false,
      _httpMessage: [Circular],
      _peername: [Object],
      [Symbol(res)]: [TLSWrap],
      [Symbol(verified)]: false,
      [Symbol(pendingSession)]: null,
      [Symbol(asyncId)]: 19,
      [Symbol(kHandle)]: [TLSWrap],
      [Symbol(kSetNoDelay)]: false,
      [Symbol(lastWriteQueueSize)]: 0,
      [Symbol(timeout)]: Timeout {
        _idleTimeout: 120000,
        _idlePrev: [TimersList],
        _idleNext: [TimersList],
        _idleStart: 18664,
        _onTimeout: [Function: bound ],
        _timerArgs: undefined,
        _repeat: null,
        _destroyed: false,
        [Symbol(refed)]: false,
        [Symbol(asyncId)]: 977,
        [Symbol(triggerId)]: 23
      },
      [Symbol(kBuffer)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBufferCb)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBufferGen)]: null,
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kBytesRead)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0,
      [Symbol(error-emitted)]: false
    },
    connection: TLSSocket {
      _tlsOptions: [Object],
      _secureEstablished: true,
      _securePending: false,
      _newSessionPending: false,
      _controlReleased: true,
      secureConnecting: false,
      _SNICallback: null,
      servername: 'localhost',
      alpnProtocol: 'http/1.1',
      authorized: false,
      authorizationError: null,
      encrypted: true,
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 11,
      connecting: false,
      _hadError: false,
      _parent: [Socket],
      _host: null,
      _readableState: [ReadableState],
      readable: true,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _writableState: [WritableState],
      writable: true,
      allowHalfOpen: false,
      _sockname: null,
      _pendingData: null,
      _pendingEncoding: '',
      server: [Server],
      _server: null,
      ssl: [TLSWrap],
      _requestCert: false,
      _rejectUnauthorized: true,
      timeout: 120000,
      parser: [HTTPParser],
      on: [Function: socketListenerWrap],
      addListener: [Function: socketListenerWrap],
      prependListener: [Function: socketListenerWrap],
      _paused: false,
      _httpMessage: [Circular],
      _peername: [Object],
      [Symbol(res)]: [TLSWrap],
      [Symbol(verified)]: false,
      [Symbol(pendingSession)]: null,
      [Symbol(asyncId)]: 19,
      [Symbol(kHandle)]: [TLSWrap],
      [Symbol(kSetNoDelay)]: false,
      [Symbol(lastWriteQueueSize)]: 0,
      [Symbol(timeout)]: Timeout {
        _idleTimeout: 120000,
        _idlePrev: [TimersList],
        _idleNext: [TimersList],
        _idleStart: 18664,
        _onTimeout: [Function: bound ],
        _timerArgs: undefined,
        _repeat: null,
        _destroyed: false,
        [Symbol(refed)]: false,
        [Symbol(asyncId)]: 977,
        [Symbol(triggerId)]: 23
      },
      [Symbol(kBuffer)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBufferCb)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBufferGen)]: null,
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kBytesRead)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0,
      [Symbol(error-emitted)]: false
    },
    _header: null,
    _onPendingData: [Function: bound updateOutgoingData],
    _sent100: false,
    _expect_continue: false,
    req: [Circular],
    locals: [Object: null prototype] {},
    _startAt: undefined,
    _startTime: undefined,
    writeHead: [Function: writeHead],
    __onFinished: [Function: listener] { queue: [Array] },
    [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
    [Symbol(kNeedDrain)]: false,
    [Symbol(corked)]: 0,
    [Symbol(kOutHeaders)]: [Object: null prototype] { 'x-powered-by': [Array] }
  },
  _startAt: [ 267748, 220273300 ],
  _startTime: 2020-10-19T01:47:48.684Z,
  _remoteAddress: '::1',
  body: { corporate_statement: false },
  _body: true,
  length: undefined,
  route: Route {
    path: '/category-statement/:corporate_statement_link_id',
    stack: [ [Layer] ],
    methods: { put: true }
  },
  [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
}
```

The error printed by `app.js`

```
// error handler
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  console.log(err.message);
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};
  console.log("this is where it's happening");
  
  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.json({ error: err })
});


body is not defined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look carefully in your code. Especially, your `PUT` route.

```js
router.put('/category-statement/:corporate_statement_link_id', function(req, res){

    console.log("req: ",req);
    // You define `reqBody`...
    var reqBody = req.body;
    var id = req.params.corporate_statement_link_id;

    // ...So where does `body` come from?
    console.log("Body: ", body);
    console.log("id:", id);


    let sql = `UPDATE corporate_statements
               SET corporate_statement = ? WHERE corporate_statement_link_id = ?`;

    db.run(sql,[reqBody.corporate_statement, id], (err, row) =>{
        if(err){
            res.status(500).send(err);
        }
        res.send(row)
    });

 })
```

As see in your code, you defined `reqBody`, assigning it the value of `req.body`. Then, you try to access the (non-existent) variable `body`. You probably meant to type `reqBody`.

Comment: OMG, it was working and I entered the first `console.log("Body: ", body)` as a test, and express was telling me that's the error it encountered. I did use `reqBody` in the db.run. Such a stupid mistake and I wasted hours trying to understand it. I'll never forget this error again. Thanks for pointing this out.